# Time complexity when j+=sqrt(i)

Tags: nested, complexity-theory, sqrt

I need to find the time complexity (in terms of theta) of this function:

```
int x = 0; 
for (int i=1; i < n ; i++) { 
  for (double j=i; j <= n ; j+=sqrt(i)) { 
    ++x; 
  } 
}
```

I know that the outer loop does n-1 iterations and the inner loop does (n-i)/sqrt(i) iterations so I need to calculate sigma of i=1 to n-1 of (n-i)/sqrt(i). Any idea how to do that?

EDIT:
Assume sqrt() runs in O(1).

Comment: What does "in terms of theta" mean?

Comment: Refer to this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations - where it says Big Theta.

Comment: "in terms of theta" implies that you want to find the complexity as a function of theta, but there is no variable theta. I assume you mean to say you want to find the Big Theta time complexity in terms of "n"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what sigma and theta mean, but sqrt is a constant time operation so it basically doesn't matter in big O notation, ie j+=sqrt(i); is the same as j+=i; is the same as j+=1;. Also (n-k) ~= n for k much less than n. This means as n gets large n-i is just n. So (n-i) * sqrt() = n * 1 = n. And you do this n times for the outer loop so n^2.

**Addition:**
As to your complicated series, I'm sure this is accurate, but it is not what we care about, we care about the order of the operation. So we need show your series is O(n^2) or K*n^2. So you have i + 2*i + ... (n-1)*i + n*i. Where i is constant so we can factor it out and wrap it up in K and are left with 1 + ... + n. This statement is dominated by n ie as n gets large n ~= (n-1), and (n-1) ~= (n-2) which implies that (n-2) ~= n. Now this doesn't hold as we approach zero, but n is so large we can drop the first say million terms. so we are left with some function that looks like
C*(n-k)*n + c. where C, k, and c are all constant. Since we don't care about constants we just care about growth as n grows we can drop all these constants and just save the n^2. Alternatively, you could show that your series is bounded by n^k*n where k goes to one as n approaches infinity, but a good logic argument is usually better. ~Ben

Comment: By sigma I meant sum (of a series). Anyway, even when n is large, i still changes from 1 to n so it must be taken into consideration. j changes values this way: i, i+sqrt(i), i+2sqrt(i)+...+i+k*sqrt(i) until i+k*sqrt(i) > n. This, together with the outer loop, results in this series: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+i%3D1+to+n+of+(n-i)%2Fsqrt(i)

Comment: How are you drawing the conclusion that sqrt is a constant time operation?

Comment: sqrt does not change the amount of time it takes to execute as n grows, thus it is constant time wrt n. ie sqrt(2) and sqrt(1000000); are both one operation.